# Retrieve Image From Firebase with Streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to Retrieve ProfileImageUrl from Firebase and i am not getting any redLines inside the console but the page crashes when i run the code and i am getting errors

The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState>#d1650):
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.

anyone knows what i am doing Wrong ?

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('loading...');
          return Container(
//            width: 150.0,
          height: 300.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 20.0),
            child: new ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document){
                return new Container(
                  width: 200,
                  child: Card(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(document['ProfileImageUrl'])
                      ],
                    ),
```

thank you all in advance

Comment: as can be see in your error document['ProfileImageUrl'] is null for some case. try to print document['ProfileImageUrl']  and make sure it is not null for any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your if statement return 'Text('loading...')' in braces and then use an else statement to return Container()